# Mobile home enclosed receptacle outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I am replacing all the enclosed mobile home receptacles with regular house receptacles. I found one enclosed mobile home receptacle with three wires, one on top and two in the bottom. (3 hots, 3 neutrals, 3 grounds. One wire is too short so I want to remove the receptacle permanently. Do I cap the 3 hots together, the 3 neutrals together and the 3 grounds together? Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you have three *cables*, one cable to the top, two to the bottom. That could be: in, out 1, out 2; or it could be: in 1, in 2, out 1 - i.e., one circuit that goes on to two other places or two *separate* circuits. Pictures would help.

Comment: You realize you need to put regular house receptacles in junction boxes, right?  The MH receptacles are special because they provide their own junction box.  And that splice also has to be in a junction box.

Comment: Yes, there will be a junction box. I am eliminating the receptacle.  Do I  put a cap on the 3 black wires all together, put a cap on the 3 white wires all together and a cap on the 3 ground wires all together,  then put a solid cover plate to close the box. The receptacle will not exist. Thank you again